# Raspberry PI 2 nodejs not installed when I turn it on

Tags: linux, node.js, raspberry-pi2, nvm

Well, i'm working with nodejs in a Raspberry Pi 2. I installed it using nvm (https://github.com/creationix/nvm) using the command:

`wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.29.0/install.sh | bash`

Then, I tested if I could execute from the terminal the programs node and npm and I could, but, when I reboot the Raspberry PI 2 I type node or npm and the terminal prompts "command not found", so I have to go and type `nvm install v4.2.2` on each startup.

Another problem that I have is that I can't execute sudo nvm, or sudo node.

I have the following questions:

- Have any of you had the same problem, and have you solved it?
- How can I uninstall nvm?
- How can I use nvm with sudo?

Answer (score 0):

NVM is not on your PATH respectively it isn't sourced on reboot.

You have to follow the manual installation guide on https://github.com/creationix/nvm.

> To activate nvm, you need to source it from your shell:
>
> . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
>
> Add these lines to your ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, or ~/.zshrc file to
>   have it automatically sourced upon login:
>
> export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && .
>   "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm

But you don't have to use nvm on a raspberry Pi, except you are really using many different versions of node. Otherwise i would recommend you to only install one version of node. Node comes with npm as default.